# Error no matching fuction for call to '' cuando uso coordx y coordy

Tags: c++

Soy nuevo en c++ y cree la clase punto sin embargo no me deja usar sus funciones

En Punto.h declare la clase:

Punto.h

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <math.h>

#ifndef Punto_h
  #define Punto_h
    class Punto {
      public :
        Punto(float x, float y);
        float coordx()const;
        float coordy()const ;
        float distancia(const Punto & otroPunto) const;
        void trasladar(float x, float y);
        bool operator==(const Punto & otroPunto)const;
      private :
        float x;
        float y;
    };
#endif // Punto
```

---

Y en Punto.cpp las funciones:

Punto.cpp

```
#include "Punto.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

Punto::Punto(float x,float y){
        this->x = x;
        this->y = y; }
float Punto :: coordx() const // supongo que tiene algun problema
 {
        return x ; }
float Punto :: coordy() const {
        return y ;}
float Punto :: distancia(const Punto & otroPunto)const{
        return sqrt(pow(x-otroPunto.x,2.0)+pow(y-otroPunto.y,2.0));}
void Punto :: trasladar(float x,float y){
        this -> x += x;
        this -> y += y; }
bool Punto :: operator==(const Punto & otroPunto)const{
        return(x==otroPunto.x)&&(y==otroPunto.y); }
```

---

Pero cuando intento usar coordx y coordy no me deja porque no encuentra una funcion para llamar y no entiendo porque :

```
void productox (Punto p, Punto q, Punto r,float res){
   float x,y ;
   Punto s;
   Punto t;
   x = coordx(p) - coordx(q); //aqui me da el error
   y = coordy(p) - coordy(q) ;
   s(x,y);
   x = (coordx(p) - coordx(r)) ;
   y = (coordy(p) - coordy(r)) ;
   t(x,y);
   res=(coordx(s)*coordy(t) - coordy(s)*coordx(t))
}
```

Le doy mil vueltas pero no termino de saber cual es el problema que me esta ocurriendo, aprecio sus respuestas, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las funciones `coordx` y `coordy` pertenecen al objeto `Punto`. Para poder llamarlas necesitas decir sobre que objeto hacerlo:

```
//               v <--- Llama 'coordx' sobre la instancia 'q'.
x = p.coordx() - q.coordx();
//  ^ <--- Llama 'coordx' sobre la instancia 'p'.
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ya me estaba dando dolor de cabeza jaja